# Adding plugins to Phonegap doesn't work

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Simple problem - when I add a plugin to even a fresh Phonegap project, it says it adds successfully but the list shows none installed.
I've reinstalled Phonegap, no joy. The plugin folder gets created and has the plugin files. This started recently on another project which before had worked. I also installed Plugman and had same problem.

[image: add a plugin]

Answer (score 0):

Try it with cordova command:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip_us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
cordova plugin ls
```